# replace class name on div with multiple classes

Tags: jquery, css

i have a div that has 3 or 4 classes on it. i need to find the class with name = "aClass" and replace it with "anotherClass". how can i do this with jquery? "aClass" could appear at any point in the classname list in different situations e.g. in one case its the first class, in another it could be the last or even the middle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass) and [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass):

```
$('.aClass').removeClass('aClass').addClass('anotherClass');
```

You can also do a string replacement on the `class` attribute, but as you see you're better off just using the first example:

```
$('.aClass').attr('class', function() {
    return $(this).attr('class').replace('aClass', 'anotherClass');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#selector').hasClass('aClass')) {
    $(this).removeClass('aClass');
    $(this).addClass('anotherClass');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question (i.e. the title) does not mention jQuery (not until the full explanation) I will contribute with my pure JS solution.

`var el = document.getElementById("myDiv");
el.className = el.className.replace(/\baClass\b/," anotherClass ");}`

This should catch "foo aClass", "aClass foo" and "foo aClass bar". Drawback: it will always add extra white space but it should not break anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not hard:

```
var replace_this = 'aClass';
var with_this    = 'anotherClass';
$('.' + replace_this).removeClass(replace_this).addClass(with_this);
```